# Being redirected to old PayPal UI incorrectly

Tags: paypal

i have integrated paypal to my ecommerce using ruby on rails but it always redirected to the old paypal UI instead of the latest UI. here is the old UI i mentioned:

[image]

here is roughly my code. once create order submit button pressed, my order controller will redirect to the encrypted paypal link.

**order_controller.rb**

```
def create
    redirect_to @order.paypal_url(root_url, shipping_fees, payment_notification_url)
```

in my order model, the encrypted link code as below:

**order.rb**

```
def paypal_url(return_url, shipping_fees, notify_url)
    encrypted = {
      :cmd => "_s-xclick",
      :encrypted => self.encrypt_for_paypal(return_url, shipping_fees, notify_url),
    }
    "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?" + encrypted.to_query
end

def encrypt_for_paypal(return_url, shipping_fees, notify_url)
#def paypal_url(return_url, shipping_fees, notify_url)
  values = {
    :business => 'cxxx@hotmail.com',
    :cmd => '_cart',
    :upload => 1,
    :currency_code => 'MYR',
    :return => return_url,
    :invoice => self.number,
    :notify_url => notify_url,
    :cert_id => "XXX",

  }

  line_items.each_with_index do |item, index|
    values.merge!({
      "amount_#{index+1}" => item.final_price,
      "item_name_#{index+1}" => Product.where(id: item.variant.product_id).pluck(:title),
      "item_number_#{index+1}" => item.variant.SKU,
      "quantity_#{index+1}" => item.quantity,
      "shipping_1" => shipping_fees
    })
  end
  encrypted_paypal(values)
end



PAYPAL_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/paypal_cert.pem")
APP_CERT_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_cert.pem")
APP_KEY_PEM = File.read("#{Rails.root}/certs/app_key.pem")

def encrypted_paypal(values)
    signed = OpenSSL::PKCS7::sign(OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(APP_CERT_PEM), OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new(APP_KEY_PEM, ''), values.map { |k, v| "#{k}=#{v}" }.join("\n"), [], OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY)
    OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt([OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new(PAYPAL_CERT_PEM)], signed.to_der, OpenSSL::Cipher::Cipher::new("DES3"), OpenSSL::PKCS7::BINARY).to_s.gsub("\n", "")
end
```

please advise because i read somewhere i need to insert :method => POST to the link but im not sure how. many thanks

Comment: How do you know this is incorrect? I see this page a lot, I presume PayPal still use it?

Comment: When in sandbox, i am redirected to the new ui. But after encryption and not in sandbox mode, i am redirected to this ui. Just want to know how to get the new ui not just in sandbox mode..

Comment: Is it maybe a PayPal setting on your profile?

Comment: so far i can't find any options to switch the UI interface in my paypal account. please advise if you have any settings needed to be done.